ASP.NET Web API : set data on startup
I have a question about loading data when running an ASP.NET Web API application. Let's say when I run the application I need to download data from the API and save it to the database. Where should I place it?
I would place it in a BackgroundService, but there is a problem that there is no guarantee that it will be loaded before the real launch.
public class StartupHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public StartupHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
             var api = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataApi>();

             var data = api.DownloadData();

             var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataDb>();

             db.Save(data);
        }
    }
}

Placing it in a startup might work too, but I've read that shouldn't be done.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Map Controllers
app.MapControllers();

app.Logger.LogInformation("Application Start" + Environment.NewLine);

var api = app.Services.GetRequiredService<DataApi>();

var data = api.DownloadData();

var db = app.Services.GetRequiredService<DataDb>();

db.Save(data);

await app.RunAsync();

Thanks a lot.

Placing it in a startup might work too, but I've read that shouldn't be done. - could you please share the article? I'd like to read it, can not imagine any real reason to avoid such implementation for now. If that data is crucial and the app won't work without it, then it seems to be pretty logical to place data fetch on startup and throw some exceptions/log errors if fetching failed.

usually you split app on layers, intteface/controllers, business layer and DAL - data layer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

@PowerMouse, yep, there could be business logic layer, as well as application logic layer. And a part of that application logic layer could be something like DataSeedService, which can be instantiated on startup and do it's job

@ArthurEdgarov, agree, but as i understood the question is how to build a client to use endpoint to save a data? background service is tricky as a scheduler - it might go off if service is going to sleep. also, why call endpoint if service can access to DAL (use DI) and call DB? for background tasks AKA background services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

@PowerMouse, as I understood - the question is where to put the fetch and seed logic. Guess we need OP here to clarify.
